# How to stop rendering a rajawali renderer object on event handler?

Tags: android, rajawali

I am rendering a rajawali renderer object as

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

// initializing camera etc.

       mSurfaceView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
        setGLBackgroundTransparent(true);
        mRenderer = new Renderer(this);
        mRenderer.setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView);
        super.setRenderer(mRenderer);
        mRenderer.setCameraPosition(0, 0, 20);

}
```

where mRenderer is an object of a class Renderer that extends rajawalirenderer

```
public class Renderer extends RajawaliRenderer 
{
...// code for rendering a textured sphere
}
```

Now I want to stop the rendering of this 3d object(sphere) on some event handler, say button click. (And once the rendering is stopped, I again want to render a different 3d object on button click.)

How can I stop the rendering of 3d object sphere?

Answer (score 1):

After searching a bit, I found the answer. There's a method named removeChild that-

Requests the removal of a child from the scene.

Parameters:
child Object3D child to be removed.
Returns:
boolean True if the child was successfully queued for removal.

Example..
getCurrentScene().removeChild(3d_Object);

where 3d_Object is the object which we don't want to render.